# Windows Forms "Deploy Task" failing with "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." in .NET5

Tags: winforms, clickonce, .net-5

I've just migrated my .NET 4.8 Windows Forms application to .NET 5.  The process was incredibly easy.  The only problem I'm having is with Deploy.  I've been using **Click Once** deploy with my application for years but after changing it to .NET5 and recreating the deploy, I'm getting this error.  I also get the same error if I use the simpler **Folder** (non Click Once) deploy option.  I'm deploying to a server share folder (`\\HYDRA\Data\SL\IceTool`) which is writable (the deploy task does actually copy the application executable into the share folder - but nothing else).

The error appears in a dialogue box containing the following text:

> Publish has encountered an error.
> Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.
>
> A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
> "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF29C.tmp"

The `tmpF29C.tmp` file contains:

> 17/12/2020 01:05:34
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---
>
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.
>
> ===================

Checking the output build log shows that the solitary `Ice.exe` file is "being used by another process":

```
2>Native image obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\R2R\Ice.dll generated successfully.
2>Skipping target "_CreateR2RSymbols" because it has no outputs.
2>Though the target has declared its outputs, the output specification only references empty properties and/or empty item lists.
2>Task "NETSdkError" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(_ReadyToRunCompilationFailures)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
2>Task "NETSdkInformation" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_ReadyToRunCompilerHasWarnings)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
2>Target "GeneratePublishDependencyFile" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(GenerateDependencyFile)' == 'true' and '$(_UseBuildDependencyFile)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('true' == 'true' and 'true' != 'true').
2>Target "ComputeDependencyFileCompilerOptions" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PreserveCompilationContext)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('' == 'true').
2>Building target "GenerateSingleFileBundle" completely.
2>Input file "C:\Workspaces\Framework\Main\Source\Core\Ice\obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\apphost.exe" is newer than output file "\\HYDRA\Data\SL\IceTool\Ice.exe".
2>Task "NETSdkError" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract)' == 'true' And '$(IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true' And 'false' != 'true').
2>Using "GenerateBundle" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\tools\net472/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.dll".
2>The "GenerateBundle" task failed unexpectedly.
2>System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '\\HYDRA\Data\SL\IceTool\Ice.exe' because it is being used by another process.
2>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
2>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
2>   at System.IO.File.OpenWrite(String path)
2>   at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.Bundle.Bundler.GenerateBundle(IReadOnlyList`1 fileSpecs)
2>   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateBundle.ExecuteCore()
2>   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
2>Target "_SGenCheckForOutputs" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)' == 'On' or ('@(WebReferenceUrl)'!='' and '$(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)' == 'Auto')) was evaluated as ('Auto' == 'On' or (''!='' and 'Auto' == 'Auto')).
2>Comparison path is "C:\Workspaces\Framework\Main\Source\Core\Ice".
2>Comparison path is "bin\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\".
2>Comparison path is "obj\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x64\".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The deploy target folder (initially empty) contains just the single `Ice.exe` file.  The same file that is "in use".

Here is my ClickOnceProfile.pub.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>3.0.0.*</ApplicationVersion>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>True</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <GenerateManifests>True</GenerateManifests>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Unc</InstallFrom>
    <InstallUrl>\\HYDRA\Data\SL\IceTool\</InstallUrl>
    <IsRevisionIncremented>True</IsRevisionIncremented>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>False</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>(removed!)</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <OpenBrowserOnPublish>false</OpenBrowserOnPublish>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <ProductName>IceTool</ProductName>
    <PublishDir>\\HYDRA\Data\SL\IceTool\</PublishDir>
    <PublishUrl>\\HYDRA\Data\SL\IceTool\</PublishUrl>
    <PublishProtocol>ClickOnce</PublishProtocol>
    <PublishReadyToRun>True</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>False</SelfContained>
    <SignatureAlgorithm>sha256RSA</SignatureAlgorithm>
    <SignManifests>True</SignManifests>
    <TargetCulture>en-GB</TargetCulture>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UpdateEnabled>True</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.NetCore.DesktopRuntime.5.0.x64">
      <Install>true</Install>
      <ProductName>.NET Desktop Runtime 5.0.1 (x64)</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Could this be a bug in a relatively new framework release? (Parallel task condition?) or any I doing something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Is your application still running in the background? Or perhaps an antivirus has locked the executable? You can check if the application runs in `Task Manager`. You can check if another process has opened a handle to your executable with  [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) or [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle).

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try to publish to a local folder?

Comment: The application isn't running in the background.  I've come back to it a day later (after a reboot) and the problem still occurs.  AV is a possibility/  When I target my local desktop (subfolder) then the deploy works fine.  I can live with that - I just need to relocate it to the share afterwards.  Luckily you can specify the final UNC path as part of the publish settings.  Thanks.

Comment: Publishing has to modify the file it creates at some point. If the publish folder is a remote folder, this process is a **lot** slower *and* may be prevented by possible write-once permissions. It's quite possible and actually *desirable* to give someone `Create`-only permissions, to avoid modification of files once they're uploaded. The entire process will be a lot faster if you publish locally then copy to the remote folder